# pyspark suffix replacement avoiding certain words without mapping to pandas or rdd

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, pyspark

I have inherited a program which modifies some strings in a pyspark dataframe. One of the steps involves removing suffixes from some words in the strings, with an additional list of exceptions that are left alone even if they have suffixes. Currently this is done by converting the dataframe to pandas with a udf, then applying a custom function to the strings in the resulting pandas dataframe, before reading back to pyspark. Unfortunately, changes to the requirements mean the code **cannot under any circumstances** use a pandas udf or be mapped to an rdd. I need to perform the same function directly in pyspark.

The suffix removing function reads in the strings word by word, checks if the word is in the exceptions list, if its not, checks for an accepted suffix (this is a strict list, I cant just use an existing stemmer), if there is, checks if the stemmed word would be over 4 characters, if it is, performs the replace.

Below is a MWE of the current implementation, after the pyspark dataframe is converted to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd


exception_list = ['WOODLAND', 'FISHING', 'LAUGHING']
suffix_list = ['ING', 'AND']

cols = ['input']
data = [
    ["CAT DOG FROG WOODLAND FARMLAND LAUGHING UNICORN"],
    ["BOG FISHING CARTING MISSING AND SOGGY"],
    ["SEARCHING"],
    ["FINDING"],
    ["SING SINGING"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df.head()


def strip_sufx_word(word, suffix, exception, min_stem_length=4):
    for sufx in suffix:
        if word[-len(sufx):] == sufx:
            if len(word[:-len(sufx)])>=min_stem_length:
                if word not in exception:
                    word = word[:-len(sufx)]
    return word


def strip_sufx_string(phrase, suffix, exception):
    new_phrase = [strip_sufx_word(word, suffix, exception)
                  for word in phrase.split()]
    return ' '.join(new_phrase)


df['output'] = df['input'].apply(strip_sufx_string,
                                 suffix=suffix_list,
                                 exception=exception_list)

df.head()
```

Any way to do this in pyspark? I am open to using things like RegexTokenizer and joining it back later, as well as creating additional truth columns which are dropped after. It just needs to be done without the dataframe ever leaving pyspark, or being mapped to anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higher order functions will be helpful here:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

exception_list = ['WOODLAND', 'FISHING', 'LAUGHING']
suffix_list = ['ING', 'AND']
min_stem_length = 4

result = sdf.withColumn(
    'exception_list', 
    F.array(*[F.lit(w) for w in exception_list])
).withColumn(
    'suffix_list', 
    F.array(*[F.lit(w) for w in suffix_list])
).withColumn(
    'output', 
    F.expr(f"""
        concat_ws(' ', 
            transform(
                split(input, ' '), 
                word -> 
                    aggregate(
                        suffix_list, 
                        word, 
                        (acc, s) -> 
                            case when substring(acc, -length(s)) = s 
                                 and length(substring(acc, 1, length(acc)-length(s))) >= {min_stem_length} 
                                 and not array_contains(exception_list, acc) 
                                 then substring(acc, 1, length(acc)-length(s)) 
                                 else acc 
                            end
                     )
            )
        )
    """
    )
).drop('exception_list', 'suffix_list')
```

```
result.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|input                                          |output                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|CAT DOG FROG WOODLAND FARMLAND LAUGHING UNICORN|CAT DOG FROG WOODLAND FARML LAUGHING UNICORN|
|BOG FISHING CARTING MISSING AND SOGGY          |BOG FISHING CART MISS AND SOGGY             |
|SEARCHING                                      |SEARCH                                      |
|FINDING                                        |FIND                                        |
|SING SINGING                                   |SING SING                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Excellent. This looks like it might solve my issues. I cant test it until I am back at work on Monday though, so i will hang on with the tick mark until then. I do have one question. In the expr, you pass suffix_list before word, but then acc before s. Why are they in reverse order?

Comment: `word` is the initial value of the accumulator `acc`, which is transformed by each `s` in the `suffix_list`, in the function `(acc, s) -> ...`

Comment: Ok. Can you expand on that a little. I cant see how word ends up as the initial value of acc. It looks like (and I admit I dont really understand expressions) suffix is passed before word. If you could explain the steps of the expression, and how the variables are parsed, that would be great (I have a similar function I need to do this for too).

Comment: See the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) for more examples. Basically it's like a for-loop, where acc is initialized with word, and the function is repeatedly called with acc as the first argument and a list element from suffix_list as the second argument, with acc being modified in each loop iteration

Comment: Similar to the [Python reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: OH! I think I see. The docs helped. To my mind, word and suffix_list were round the wrong way. But now I see that aggregate takes the arguments as expression then the start point. Word is the start point, right?

Comment: Exactly @AlexHoward

Comment: Worked exactly as expected - marked as answer. Thank you.